# swiftui text is not centered

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-text

The code I used below is not center centered. the top space is twice as much as the bottom space. Don't need to be equal to the bottom and top space? How I can center Text?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment:.center) {
            Color.red
            
            Text("onna")
                .font(.system(size: 60))
        }
        .frame(width: 222, height: 60)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The text is vertically centered relative to CAPITAL letters. If you change it to "ONNA" you'll see it.

Comment: If you never expect to have any capital letters, you can use some bottom padding. `.padding(.bottom, 10)` seems to work for the text of this size.

Comment: Your example is not a good example to show the issue, however the things you are trying to show exists, there is a human guideline about the values for text in apple website, I believe you can change them. But I would not recommend, the text guideline should be respected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a way for you to set the value you want:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 10.0) {
            
            Text("Onna")
                .font(.system(size: 60))
                .baselineOffset(-40.0)
                .background(Color.red)
            
            Text("Onna")
                .font(.system(size: 60))
                .baselineOffset(40.0)
                .background(Color.blue)
            
        }

    }
}
```